# Converted byte array to an image but not showing

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, windows-8

I am converting a byte array retrieved from database to an image. It is converted-i think- successfully but not showing an image in the image box. Here's the code I am implementing. If anyone of you help, please.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            Service1Client GetNameFromService = new Service1Client();
            GetNameRequest NameRequest = new GetNameRequest();
            NameRequest.username = e.Parameter.ToString();
            GetNameResponse NameResponse = await GetNameFromService.GetNameAsync(NameRequest);
            lblName.Text = NameResponse.GetNameResult.NAME;
            byte[] IMG = NameResponse.GetNameResult.IMAGE;

            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream raStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {

                using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(raStream))
                {
                    // Write the bytes to the stream
                    writer.WriteBytes(IMG);

                    // Store the bytes to the MemoryStream
                    await writer.StoreAsync();

                    // Not necessary, but do it anyway
                    await writer.FlushAsync();

                    // Detach from the Memory stream so we don't close it
                    writer.DetachStream();
                }

                raStream.Seek(0);

                BitmapImage bitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitMapImage.SetSource(raStream);

                imgUser.Source = bitMapImage;
            }

            //var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            //await stream.WriteAsync(IMG.AsBuffer());

            //BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            //image.SetSource(stream);
            //imgUser.Source = image;

            ID = NameResponse.GetNameResult.id;

            await GetNameFromService.CloseAsync();
        }`
```

Image is retrieved through web service. The code for the method of web service is below,

```
        public GetDetail GetDetail(string username)
    {
        StoryMakerConnection.Open();
        GetDetail GD = new GetDetail();
        SqlCommand GetIDCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId FROM LoginInfo WHERE UserName LIKE '" + username + "'", StoryMakerConnection);
        SqlDataReader IDReader = GetIDCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (IDReader.Read())
        {
            GD.ID = Convert.ToInt16(IDReader["UserId"].ToString());
        }
        IDReader.Close();
        SqlCommand GetNameCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserFirstName, UserLastName, Picture FROM UserInfo WHERE UserId = " + GD.ID, StoryMakerConnection);
        SqlDataReader NameReader = GetNameCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (NameReader.Read())
        {
            GD.FullName = NameReader["UserFirstName"].ToString() + " " + NameReader["UserLastName"].ToString();
            GD.img = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(NameReader["Picture"].ToString());
        }
        return GD;
    }
```

Comment: I can't tell for certain... but it looks to be scope issue, you create your `BitmapImage` within the brackets before your commented out code, try declaring it outside of this scope (preferably in a using block if its a disposable object)

Comment: If I declare BitmapImage outside the bracket, it gives an error. Because raStream should be within bracket.

Comment: Your commented code confused me at first.. you can declare the bitmapimage outside of the brackets but then set the source inside the brackets still.. If you set a breakpoint outside of the brackets, does imgUser have a valid source or is it null?

Comment: I tried, but it is still not working